# exc_breakpoint(code=exc_arm_breakpoint subcode=0xe7ffdefe) soapaction

Tags: swift, web-services, soap, xcode7

i want from a web service some lists. If i want the one List of the web service i get fatal error :( if i take a other list from web service i get the full list. I want show the list in the tableview.

Can someone help me?
I use Xcode 7 with swift 2 on ipad device with 8.4!
greetz

Code:
That works!

```
func fillTbaleView(){        
    soap.setValue("99999", forKey: "nummer")
    soap.requestURL("http://.../WebService.asmx",
        soapAction: "http://.../getTi",
        completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : Int, dict : [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in

            var book:Dictionary = dict as Dictionary
            let ti:NSArray = book["Ti"] as! NSArray
            self.ti = ti
            self.tbl_View.reloadData()

        }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in

            NSLog("%@", error)
    }
}    
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.ti.count
}    
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = self.tbl_View.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell?        
    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }        
    let chapter_verse:NSDictionary = self.ti[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary        
    let nummer:String = chapter_verse["TiNumber"] as! String
    let name:String = chapter_verse["TiName"] as! String        
    cell!.textLabel?.text = String(format: "TiNummer: %@ TiName: %@", nummer, name)
    return cell!
}
```

That doesn't work

```
func fillTbaleView(sender: AnyObject) {               
    soap.setValue("999", forKey: "Adressnummer")
    soap.requestURL("http://.../WebService.asmx",
        soapAction: "http://.../getKu",
        completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : Int, dict : [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in                
            var book:Dictionary = dict as Dictionary
            let ku:NSArray = book["ku"] as! NSArray
            self.ku = ku
            self.tbl_View.reloadData()                
        }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in                
            NSLog("%@", error)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.ku.count
}    
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell? = self.tbl_View.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell?        
    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }        
    let chapter_verse:NSDictionary = self.ku[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary        
    let nummer:String = chapter_verse["KuNummer"] as! String
    let name:String = chapter_verse["KuName"] as! String        
    cell!.textLabel?.text = String(format: "KuNummer: %@ KuName: %@", nummer, name)
    //cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = text
    return cell!
}
```

The both web service methods do the same on safari looks fine but if i want the second in my app than i get error!

Comment: Where is the error thrown and of what type is soap?

Comment: the type of soap is: var soap = [SOAPEngine]() from https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine and the error came: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=4a7ca0-1447684146.png

Comment: Where is the error thrown?

Comment: Did you try filing an issue here? https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine/issues 
Or do you expect SO users to fix any 3rd party library?

Comment: i find the problem it was a  stupid exception from me. I write the wrong value and than make the tool the crash!!! Sorry for my personal error :(